# Double entry accounting: data types for efficiency?

Tags: mysql, database, accounting

Started designing databases very recently. I am wondering if I chose the right data types.
For example, I was told to use integers for $ amounts to avoid troubles. Also for tax rates I put decimals, I assume I will have to convert it back to integer when calculated.

Thanks!

Database design:

[image: Database design]

Comment: Please [edit] the question and tell us which table and column in particular you're concerned about. What is it supposed to model from the real world and what are the demands and limitations the real world applies to it? Also who told you about the integers and what "troubles" do they mean? And please preferably post tables as `CREATE` statements as **text**, **not** images.

Comment: There is a school of thought like that, but I'd be happy with decimals myself

Comment: It's worth noting there's a *huge* difference between `DECIMAL`, as in *fixed-place*, and `FLOAT`, as in floating-point. The former is predictable. The latter is a whole lot of hurt if you're not prepared for it.

Answer (score 1):

Integers work great for integers, but not decimals. You can store pennies (or a thousandth of a penny) in an integer and then convert to to dollars when you display it in much the same way that we store dates as "seconds since 1st Jan 1970" but display them differently.

the trick there is to ensure your conversion always applies, and that's not so easy when using a common datatype like Integer.

DBs all have a [decimal datatype](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-decimal/) that is fixed precision (NOT float or double) so use that and everyone will be less confused as to what it going on with a currency entry.

Comment: If the fixed-place datatype is matched with a fixed-place equivalent in application code you'll be fine. If not, watch out!